# Better way of writing a nested query in SQl

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a piece of code and I was wondering if there is a more elegant, more efficient way of writing it.

```
SELECT act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID FROM CPMS.ACTIVITY_TRANSACTION act1
  WHERE act1.USER_CREATED ='CPMSAutoRecovery'
  AND act1.TRANSACTION_GROUP_ID =23    --commitment, not entitled
  GROUP BY  act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID HAVING COUNT(*)>1
  AND act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID IN (
    select ad.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID from CPMS.activity_detail ad, CPMS.PARTY_ROLE pr 
    where pr.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY_ID = ad.activity_registry_id 
    AND pr.PARTY_ROLE_type_ID=2 
    AND pr.PARTY_ID IN (
      select distinct i.PARTY_ID FROM CPMS.INDIVIDUAL i, CPMS.PARTY_ROLE pr where 
      I.PARTY_ID = PR.PARTY_ID AND i.EXPIRY_DATE is null
    )
  )
  order by act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID;
```

this is the key dependencies of the tables:

```
INDIVIDUAL
----------
PARTY_ID
PARTY_ROLE

------------
ACTIVITY_REGISTRY_ID 
PARTY_ID

ACTIVITY_DETAIL
-----------------
ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID 
ACTIVITY_REGISTRY_ID

ACTIVITY_TRANSACTION
----------------------
ACTIVITY_TRANSACTION_ID 
ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID
```

UPDATE:
I made it a JOIN

```
SELECT act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID FROM CPMS.ACTIVITY_TRANSACTION act1
JOIN CPMS.ACTIVITY_DETAIL ad ON act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID = ad.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID
JOIN CPMS.PARTY_ROLE pr ON ad.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY_ID = pr.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY_ID
JOIN CPMS.INDIVIDUAL i ON pr.PARTY_ID = i.PARTY_ID
  WHERE act1.USER_CREATED ='CPMSAutoRecovery'
  AND act1.TRANSACTION_GROUP_ID =23
  AND pr.PARTY_ROLE_type_ID=2 
  AND i.EXPIRY_DATE is null
  GROUP BY  act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID HAVING COUNT(*)>1
order by act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID;
```

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi it's Oracle

Comment: @jarlh Is this what you mean?                                                     `SELECT act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID FROM CPMS.ACTIVITY_TRANSACTION act1
JOIN CPMS.ACTIVITY_DETAIL ad ON act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID = ad.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID
JOIN CPMS.PARTY_ROLE pr ON ad.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY_ID = pr.ACTIVITY_REGISTRY_ID
JOIN CPMS.INDIVIDUAL i ON pr.PARTY_ID = i.PARTY_ID
WHERE act1.USER_CREATED ='CPMSAutoRecovery'
AND act1.TRANSACTION_GROUP_ID =23
AND pr.PARTY_ROLE_type_ID=2 
AND i.EXPIRY_DATE is null
GROUP BY  act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID HAVING COUNT(*)>1
order by act1.ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID;`

Comment: Oops, I was talking about the sub-query alone. Since I don't know the database design I wouldn't dare to remove it. I'd keep it, but improve it.

Comment: @jarlh see my question for better format of the `JOIN` it gives the same result as the original query

Comment: That looks good! That's exactly what I was going to suggest. I think most people would also move the WHERE conditions from joined tables into their JOIN ON clauses (like `pr.PARTY_ROLE_type_ID=2`), but your way isn't wrong.

Comment: @kfinity I don't think most people would do that.  Isn't the whole point of the ANSI join syntax to separate the JOIN conditions from the WHERE conditions?